# Django dates calculator

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

this application should take a date from the user, store it in the database then count 9 days after it and show those 10 days in a list, I managed to make two views one to count the 10 days and show them in a list. The other view is to take the day from the user and store it in the database, now I want to connect both so by the end of the process I want the user to select the date then the application automatically stores the date and counts them and return the list.

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import DateField
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import CharField, Model


# Create your models here
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
        
class PeriodDate(models.Model):
    per_date = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

serializer:

```
from dataclasses import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PeriodDate

class PeriodDateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PeriodDate
        fields = '__all__'
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('CalendarCount', views.CalendarCount, name= 'index' ),
    path('form', views.form),
  

]
```

Views:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def CalendarCount(request):
    #Taking date
    Slected_date = PeriodDate.objects.all()
    #Change data type from Str into Date
    First_date= datetime.strptime(Slected_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    #Making a list to store dates after the for loop
    dd = []
    #A loop to count 9 days after the First_date
    for i in range(9):
        a_date = (First_date + timedelta(days = i))
        #changing Date form to show the day only
        a_date = a_date.strftime('%d')
        #store results into the dd list
        dd.append(a_date)
        #str(dd.append(d1 + timedelta(days=i)))
    return Response(dd)

@api_view(['POST'])
def form(request):
    serlializer = PeriodDateSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serlializer.is_valid():
        serlializer.save()
    return  Response(serlializer.data)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I use the same date that I got with the post method into the first view the "CalendarCount" view

Comment: You will need to keep the id of the `PeriodDate` object that you create with the POST.

Comment: I would actually take a different approach and have the user enter the `start` and `end` for an event directly. I don't think `PeriodDate` is even necessary.